# Inconsistent output from an auto encoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

In the following code, I define an encoder and a decoder. The model is applied to an input array `data` and calculates `predicted_data` using the decoder:

1. the 2 matrices differ which is shown by `ǹorm_difference` I can understand that this may be due to the approximation
2. however, upon running the program several times I get different values of `ǹorm_difference` despite having set the seed value for the random numbers. So I start having doubts on the program correctness.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

seed_value = 42
np.random.seed(seed_value)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
data = np.random.rand(1000, 64)  # Assuming 1000 data samples with 64 features each

input_dim = data.shape[1]
latent_dim = 32  # Adjust this according to your desired latent space size

INPUT = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
encoded = Dense(60, activation='relu')(INPUT)
encoded = Dense(58, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(56, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(50, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(46, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(40, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(40, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(46, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(50, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(56, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(58, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(60, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation='linear')(decoded)  # Use 'linear' activation here

autoencoder = Model(INPUT, decoded)
encoder = Model(INPUT, encoded) 
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_layer = decoder_input
for i in range(len(autoencoder.layers) - 7, len(autoencoder.layers)):
    decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[i](decoder_layer)
decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_layer)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
#autoencoder.summary()
encoder.summary()
decoder.summary()
autoencoder.fit(data, data, epochs=50, batch_size=32)

latent_representation = encoder.predict(data)
predicted_data = decoder.predict(latent_representation)
norm_A = np.linalg.norm(data)
norm_B = np.linalg.norm(predicted_data)

# Calculate the difference in norms
norm_difference = abs(norm_A - norm_B)
print(norm_difference)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting different values for `norm_difference` despite setting the random seed is due to the TensorFlow operations involving GPU utilization which still introduces non-deterministic behavior even when using a fixed random seed.

you need to to control the GPU usage and set an environment variable to fix the GPU behavior which can be done by adding

```py
import os
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```

And you need to set the following configuration in TensorFlow

```py
import tensorflow as tf


# Add these lines before creating the model
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=config)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```